# Error on running a Ruby Application

Tags: ruby, aptana3

I'm building an enigma machine simulator in ruby using aptana studio 3 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

When I run the application the following error occurs:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- enigma/rotor.rb (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/xxxx/Downloads/enigma-ruby-master/lib/enigma.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you added the require code from your ruby file, but I suspect the following

rotor.rb is a file you have created in your enigma project, and is contained in the enigma folder

your require should be

```
require './enigma/rotor'
```

or
    require './enigma/rotor.rb'

if the enigma directory is a sub-directory of the one you are currently operating in

```
require './rotor'
```

or
    require './rotor'

This will say to source the file locally and not to look through the general libraries or gem's you may have added

Comment: That did it. THanks